# difference maven build in same pom file.

Tags: eclipse, maven

i have a parent pom file that include 3 module...

and there is difference when i run "mvn install" from command line on the "parent pom" to eclipse m2 plugin (run-- maven install).

i can see it when i run from command line it's not and after that try to run "clean" on my tomcat server it show me this error:

Publishing failed
Publishing failed with multiple errors

```
File not found: D:\Projects\starto-v1\Tomcat Servlet\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF.
File not found: D:\Projects\starto-v1\Tomcat Servlet\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\starto.starto\MavenWeb-starto\pom.properties.
File not found: D:\Projects\starto-v1\Tomcat Servlet\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\starto.starto\MavenWeb-starto\pom.xml.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/MeetReq/MeetReqHandler$1.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/MeetReq/MeetReqHandler.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/MsgReq/MsgReqHandler$1.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/MsgReq/MsgReqHandler.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/Servlets/HelloWorldServlet.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/Servlets/LocUpdateServlet.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/Servlets/MeetServlet.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/Servlets/MsgServlet.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/Servlets/SearchServlet.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/Servlets/SingInUpOut.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/Servlets/c2dm.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/Servlets/imAlive.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/c2dm/FakeHostnameVerifier.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/c2dm/NameValuePair.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/c2dm/c2dmReqHandler$1.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/c2dm/c2dmReqHandler.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/db/managment/Dbconnection.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/db/managment/DbquaryExecutor.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/net/viralpatel/maven/ReqHandler.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/search/SearchReqHandler.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/servlet/common/CommonFun.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/signInUpOutReq/SignInUpOutReqHandler$1.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/signInUpOutReq/SignInUpOutReqHandler.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/update/imAlive/IsAliveChecker.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/update/imAlive/IsAliveCheckerThread.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/update/imAlive/imAliveReqHandler$1.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/update/imAlive/imAliveReqHandler.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/update/loc/req/UpdateLocReqHandler$1.class'.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/MavenWeb-starto/target/classes/update/loc/req/UpdateLocReqHandler.class'.
File not found: D:\Projects\starto-v1\Hibernett\target\classes\META-INF\maven\starto.starto\Hibernet-starto\pom.properties.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Common-starto/target/classes/Entities/LocationStartTo.class'.
```

(this file he throw "File not found" they really not there...)

but if i go to my parent pom run-->"maven install" it's run just fine with no error when i try to clean..

what could be the  reason?

i try to see if "my maven" that run in command line is different maven from eclipse but i didn't find which maven run in eclipse...

thanks in advance..

sorry for my English...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run maven outside of eclipse, files are changed outside of eclipse. What you need to do is, refresh (f5) your project within eclipse after building it via maven outside of eclipse. Then that "out of sync" error will go away.

```
window -> preferences -> maven -> installations ->
```

you can change maven installation from here if you need to

Comment: :) lol, that happens all the time to everyone. no need to feel like that