# file not found manifest.mf eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, manifest.mf

I'm using the following configuration :

- Eclipse Indigo
- Maven 2
- ClearCase (like SVN and CVS)

and every time I want to run an application within eclipse a popup appears telling me that a *Problem has occured : File not found : ...\target\classes\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF*.

Comment: does the file in that path exist?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, actually no, neither in ClearCase nor in Eclipse!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810236/difference-maven-build-in-same-pom-file

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Go to the root of the project. Wherever the pom is located then try to do a

```
 mvn eclipse:clean
```

Then refresh your projects and see where that leaves you

Comment: `Deleting file: .project     Deleting directory: .settings` I guess somehow that completely destroyed it for me.

Comment: after the clean, you should run mvn eclipse:eclipse too

Comment: `mvn eclipse:clean` will remove the Maven Nature for an eclipse project.

Answer (score 29):

Right click on project then click on maven then do update project.It work for me.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me: `Eclipse > Project > Maven > Update project`.

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 
Eclipse > Project > Maven > Update project Works for me.

Answer (score 14):

I had the similar issue. What I did is:

1. Right click on *project > Maven > Disable Maven Nature*
2. Right click on *project > configure> Convert to maven project*

Error gone

Comment: Eclipse/maven were wrong. It's astounding this errors continue being there for years and years.

Comment: 1/19/24 checking in.  I did these steps & this solved the problem

Answer (score 8):

If you're also using Maven and sometimes compiling outside of Eclipse, it could be removing Eclipse's manifest, and Eclipse won't recognize the manifest that external Maven creates.

> TL;DR Uncheck "*Maven Archiver generates files under the build
>   directory*" in `Window > Preferences > Maven > WTP`.

Read more in @cosjav's answer [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659891/m2e-wtp-error-path-target-m2e-wtp-web-resources-meta-inf-manifest-mf-no-such).

Answer (score 4):

Right click on **project** -> **Maven** -> **Update**

DEBUG or RUN the server in order to fetch the recently created war file.

Make sure to check "Force update snapshots/releases" while doing MAVEN UPDATE

Answer (score 2):

**clean all (involved) projects** and **refresh your open projects in your workspace**

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has already been answered. After several tries, what worked for me was expanded my project in eclipse, right clicked on target directory and clicked refresh and that has been working ever since. Hope this works for someone if all the above fails.

Comment: I followed the above , it worked for me .i have scenario like I am creating jar from one project and refering the same in another web project as dependency . Tomcat failed to start with concurrent Exception and saxparser not created error.

Answer (score 1):

All. For me, there was an error in pom.xml. I formatted the code (Ctrl+Shift+F) and the error is gone. After that I was able to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Close the eclipse and start the eclipse again. This will refresh the projects and problem will be solved.

Comment: Not necessary to close Eclipse, just refresh the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it got resolved just
disturb the formatting  of

> **POM.xml**

and press

> **ctrl+a** and **ctrl+shift+f** then save the document

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project then select maven and then click on Update project after select the project name and update it'll be work fine.

Comment: How your answer is different from the existing posted answer for e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41672688/2987755, if it is same, please do not post it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared to me while I updated eclipse [updated to Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18)] as my project was open in eclipse. Then I closed my CLI (as I was running mvn test command), closed the project in eclipse and restarted my eclipse.
Thereafter the issue was gone. Hopefully this will resolve your issue too.