# Maven and manifest

Tags: java, spring, maven

All works fine, but after I add one more class to my Eclipse Dynamic Web Project, Maven starts:

> \target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (file not found)

I don't do anymore - how to heal it - tell me PLZ. Of course I clean my Maven project and reinstall it, but nothing change. Here is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>TrendSoft</groupId>
<artifactId>TrendSoft</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.1208</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Why changing the defaults? What is the reason to use `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root of the project. Wherever the pom is located then try to do a

```
mvn eclipse:clean
```

Then

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

For more, you can go through this tutorial: [m2e-wtp error: <path>/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659891/m2e-wtp-error-path-target-m2e-wtp-web-resources-meta-inf-manifest-mf-no-such)

Answer (score 0):

I think this was an Eclipse bug. Before I **Run as** Maven build with command `clean install`.
Now I just Run as Maven Clean, then Run Maven install and problem gone.

Thanks all for ideas.