# Spring boot web application with war file

Tags: spring-boot

I create a **Spring boot maven application** where executable is war when the application is imported in **Eclipse** I get the following error in **pom file**

```
org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration)
```

If the application executable is jar the problem is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Guess eclipse can't find your manifest file. Usually, it's in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

Answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350130/file-not-found-manifest-mf-eclipse?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) could be helpful.