# The system cannot find the path specified (MANIFEST.MF)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, pom.xml

I get the following Tomcat error:

> 'Publishing to Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost...' has encountered a problem.
>   Publishing failed with multiple errors.

Details:

> Publishing failed with multiple errors
>
> > File not found: C:\Users...\HerramientaOntologica\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF.
> >
> > File not found: C:\Users...\HerramientaOntologica\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\HerramientaOntologica\HerramientaOntologica\pom.properties.
> >
> > File not found: C:\Users...\HerramientaOntologica\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\HerramientaOntologica\HerramientaOntologica\pom.xml.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen. I have deployed others projects on the same Tomcat server (8.5.31). The setup is the same.

So far, I have tried:

- Doing a Maven->Update project.
- Cleaning the Tomcat server.
- Cleaning the project.
- Closing and starting Eclipse.
- Refreshing the project.
- Refreshing the target directory.
- Disabling Maven Nature and converting to maven project again.

Any of the above solutions I found works for me.

This is what appears in my console.

```
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HerramientaOntologica]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HerramientaOntologica]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@6863a298]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5042)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6c068c42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:140)
    ... 13 more

jul 03, 2018 6:48:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

jul 03, 2018 6:48:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:681)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350130/file-not-found-manifest-mf-eclipse

Comment: @DhruvSinghal I have tried these methods, but still I get the same error.

Comment: Tried restart eclipse, maven update project, refresh, clean and build?

Comment: You can also try clearing the maven repositories from local, and rebuild. Maybe that can help. Also try cleaning ALL related projects (if any). If nothing helps, try update all projects with Force update snapshots/releases.

Comment: @DhruvSinghal clearing the maven repositories worked.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the content of my repository folder and it worked. It seems the main problem is any corrupted jar.
The following question helped:
[Deploying Maven project throws java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090921/deploying-maven-project-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-loc-header-b)