# STS 3.9.11 @autowired of an JPA @entity no longer works with STS 4.5.1

Tags: windows, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite, jdk1.7

We are preparing to migrate a legacy JDK 1.7 Spring Tool Suite 3 webapp (tomcat 8) to STS 4 with JDK 11 (tomcat 9).

If I import the maven project into STS 3.9.11, the @AutoWired properties of some @Entity class are populated property, but this stops working if I import the same projet in STS 4.5.1 (still at JDK 1.7).

I've made some research on to why the injection is not working in an @Entity, and apparently its normal, the class is instantiated be the db framework, not by the Spring framework. One work-around is to extend the @Entity class with SpringBeanAutowiringSupport, or create some kind of "context.xml" to do acheive the same thing (I'm new to Spring and Beans and JPA).

I would like to know why its working with STS 3,9.11 but not with STS 4.5.1, and what would be the best solution using JDK 11.

SuperPom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ca.qc.gouv.cnt.superpom</groupId>
<artifactId>SuperPom</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>7</java.version>
    <war.name>DEFAULT_WAR_NAME</war.name>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories> 

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create-timestamp</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${war.name}</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${timestamp}</Implementation-Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>false</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.3,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>create-timestamp</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute></execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ca.qc.gouv.cnt.sec</groupId>
<artifactId>SecuriteCnesst</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
<name>SecuriteCnesst</name>
<parent>
    <groupId>ca.qc.gouv.cnt.superpom</groupId>
    <artifactId>SuperPom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>   
<properties>
    <war.name>SecuriteCnesst</war.name>
    <tiles.version>3.0.3</tiles.version>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.23</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.qc.gouv.cnt</groupId>
        <artifactId>Securite-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.qc.gouv.cnt</groupId>
        <artifactId>WebApp-Commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.qc.gouv.cnt</groupId>
        <artifactId>WebApp-Commons2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>
                    jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec
                </artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>
                    jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec
                </artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Property not injected:

```
@Entity
@Configurable
@Table(name = "SADR11_SUBST_APLIC_INTRV")
public class Substitution extends BaseAuditable {
    
    @Transient
    @Autowired
    private BottinService bottinService;
```

WebAppConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public BottinService bottinService() {
    BottinService bottinService = new BottinService();
    bottinService.setCacheMinutes(10);
    return bottinService;
}
```

Comment: I've turned on logging. There is a difference between the bean creation sequence in the working version and the non-working one. Working one:  "- Finished creating instance of bean 'localeResolver', Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'bottinService'". Version which does not: "Finished creating instance of bean 'viewResolver', Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'bottinService'"

Comment: Hard to say why there is a difference when using this project in STS 3.x compared to STS 4.x. Can you open an issue and attach a sample project for us to look at? https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues

Answer (score 0):

It now works with STS 4.5.1. I was building the 5 inter-dependant projects on the command line in the console (mvn.cmd clean install) having and fixing errors in SuperPom.xml and Pom.xml (AspectJ not finding Superclass Object, and javax.annotation not being there).

If I build using the Eclipse menu only, Project Maven update, clean, then Install, there is no more errors during build, and the @Autowire works like before in STS 3.9.11.

Go the idea from this post:
[file not found manifest.mf eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350130/file-not-found-manifest-mf-eclipse)