# Jar does not contain plugin.yml - not sure why?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I have the following code below.

I am creating a plugin for Minecraft using the **Spigot/Bukkit** API and the **java programming language**.

I have created this using the **maven** tool on **eclipse**.

I enter **mvn clean package** into the terminal on my mac to compile the '.jar' file.

I then drag this '.jar' file into my **'plugins'** folder on my server.

However, I keep getting the issue: **java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml**

I am not sure why the jar file **does not contain** the plugin.yml.

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

**pom.xml** file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>newestfile.here</groupId>
  <artifactId>newestplugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.10.1</version>       
              <configuration>
                  <release>17</release>
              </configuration>   
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
          <id>papermc-repo</id>
          <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.papermc.paper</groupId>
          <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

**plugin.yml** file:

```
name:newestplugin
main:newestfile.here.newestplugin.Main 
version:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
api-version: 1.19
```

The top few lines of my **'.java'** file:

```
package newestfile.here.newestplugin;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.File;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitTask;
import java.nio.file.Files; 

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener
{
    boolean stopRepeater;
```

Organisation of **nesting** of packages:

[image]

Comment: Could you show how you nested the files in your project? EG a file tree showing the `pom.xml` at the root, the java source code at `src/main/<package>/<class>.java` and the `plugin.yml` at `resources/main/plugin.yml`

Comment: Have added above - is that what you mean? Showing which package is in which folder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should precise in the `pom.xml` file, in the `<build>` section:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>plugin.yml</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

If you have another file to add (for example `config.yml`), just copy the line `<include>plugin.yml</include>`.

Comment: it now says; /Users/macbook/eclipse-workspace/newestplugin/target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory) on my pom.xml file. Why might this be?

Comment: It's another problem that can be fixed with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22722750/10952503) answer for example

Comment: Thanks so much for your support! I have finally managed to get it working after days of persevering :)

Answer (score 0):

My code finally worked with the following:

**plugin.yml:**

```
name: newestplugin
main: newestfile.here.newestplugin.Main 
version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
api-version: 1.19
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>newestfile.here</groupId>
  <artifactId>newestplugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
   <resources>
     <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>plugin.yml</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
   </resources>   
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.10.1</version>       
              <configuration>
                  <release>17</release>
              </configuration>   
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
          <id>papermc-repo</id>
          <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.papermc.paper</groupId>
          <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```